# Performance Issues with Zipped Archives in PHP

Tags: php, database, zip

## First Some Background

I'm planning out the architecture for a new PHP web application and trying to make it as easy as possible to install.  As such, I don't care what web server the end user is running so long as they have access to PHP (setting my requirement at PHP5).

But the app *will* need some kind of database support.  Rather than working with MySQL, I decided to go with an embedded solution.  A few friends recommended SQLite - and I might still go that direction - but I'm hesitant since it needs additional modules in PHP to work.

Remember, the aim is easy of installation ... most lay users won't know what PHP modules their server has or even how to find their `php.ini` file, let alone enable additional tools.

## My Current Objective

So my current leaning is to go with a filesystem-based data store.  The "database" would be a folder, each "table" would be a specific subfolder, and each "row" would be a file within that subfolder.  For example:

```
/public_html
    /application
        /database
            /table
                1.data
                2.data
            /table2
                1.data
                2.data
```

There would be other files in the database as well to define schema requirements, relationships, etc.  But this is the *basic* structure I'm leaning towards.

I've been pretty happy with the way Microsoft built their Open Office XML file format (`.docx`/`.xlsx`/etc).  Each file is really a ZIP archive of a set of XML files that define the document.

It's clean, easy to parse, and easy to understand.

I'd like to actually set up my directory structure so that `/database` is really a ZIP archive that resides on the server - a single, portable file.

But as the data store grows in size, won't this begin to affect performance on the server?  Will PHP need to read the *entire* archive in to memory to extract it and read its composite files?

What alternatives could I use to implement this kind of file structure but still make it as portable as possible?

Comment: [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php): *"The SQLite3 extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0."*. :)

Comment: I'd say you would learn most if you just go on like you think and then run into practical problems. However from what you outline I'm inclined to say that you're handling your design awfully wrong. Even wordpress which somewhat followed your maxime over the last 10 years and well, they even started with mysql. You must be really crazy to re-invent the wheel and then complain about the downsides of doing so.

Comment: MySQL has its own problems - the largest of which is that it requires configuration. Non-tech users shy away from anything that looks like setup when they install a "one click" application. That's why so many people stick with ****y hosts like GoDaddy who abstract the configuration steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite is enabled by default since PHP5 so most all PHP5 users should have it.

I think there will be tons of problems with the zip approach, for example adding a file to a relatively large zip archive is very time consuming.  I think there will be horrible concurrency and locking issues.

Reading zip files requires a php extension anyway, unless you went with a pure PHP solution.  The downside is most php solutions WILL want to read the whole zip into memory, and will also be way slower than something that is written in C and compiled like the zip extension in PHP.

I'd choose another approach, or make SQLite/MySQL a requirement.  If you use PDO for PHP, then you can allow the user to choose SQLite or MySQL and your code is no different as far as issuing queries.  I think 99%+ of webhosts out there support MySQL anyway.

Comment: The difference between MySQL and SQLite is the setup component. But since everyone keeps telling me SQLite is supported out of the box for PHP5 I guess it's safe. My hesitation is that people have been telling me that about other modules (i.e. GD) for ages and have been wrong time and again, despite what the PHP manual claims.

Comment: Understandable.  GD is a bit different as it is usually enabled by default, but has several external dependencies that do require special packages (libpng, zlib, libjpeg, FreeType for TTF).  If gd is enabled, but the system doesn't have freetype, then the particular system can't use any TTF functions, or if zlib isn't installed, they can't write png images etc.  I think with SQLite, you are a bit safer.  Also note, SQLite3 is default in PHP 5.3.0, SQlite (2) is enabled since PHP 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Using a real database will also affect your performance. It's worth loading the extra modules (and most PHP installations have at least the mysql module and probably sqlite as well) for the fact that those modules are written in C and run much faster than PHP, and have been optimized for speed. Using sqlite will help keep your web app portable, if you're willing to deal with sqlite BS.

Answer (score 0):

Zip archives are great for data exchange. They aren't great for fast access, though, and they're awful for rewriting content. Both of these are extremely important for a database used by a web application.

Your proposed solution also has some specific performance issues -- the list of files in a zip archive is internally stored as a "flat" list, so accessing a file by name takes `O(n)` time relative to the size of the archive.